# The volume “boot” has only 0 byte disk space remaining?

Tags: boot

I am in Ubuntu 12.04.

When I install the software updates with "Update Manager", there is a pop up dialog which tells me "The volume "boot" has only 0 byte disk space remaining"

My current kernal in use is:

```
myname: ~$ uname -r
3.11.0-19-generic
```

The content of boot folder is:

```
Laptop1:~$ ls -lah /boot
total 215M
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 2,0K abr 26 14:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4,0K abr 26 14:48 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 983K oct 23  2013 abi-3.11.0-13-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 983K nov 12 18:33 abi-3.11.0-14-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 983K ene 30 18:53 abi-3.11.0-15-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 984K feb  3 23:20 abi-3.11.0-17-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 985K mar 11 20:06 abi-3.11.0-19-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 985K abr  1 23:08 abi-3.11.0-20-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 160K oct 23  2013 config-3.11.0-13-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 160K nov 12 18:33 config-3.11.0-14-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 160K ene 30 18:53 config-3.11.0-15-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 160K feb  3 23:20 config-3.11.0-17-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 160K mar 11 20:06 config-3.11.0-19-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 160K abr  1 23:08 config-3.11.0-20-generic
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 1,0K abr 26 14:48 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  26M nov 23 17:56 initrd.img-3.11.0-13-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  26M dic 24 14:55 initrd.img-3.11.0-14-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  26M feb  1 20:46 initrd.img-3.11.0-15-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  26M feb 22 14:00 initrd.img-3.11.0-17-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  26M abr 22 20:57 initrd.img-3.11.0-19-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  26M abr 26 14:48 initrd.img-3.11.0-20-generic
drwx------  2 root root  12K oct 30 21:03 lost+found
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 173K jun 17  2013 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 175K jun 17  2013 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root 3,2M oct 23  2013 System.map-3.11.0-13-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3,2M nov 12 18:33 System.map-3.11.0-14-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3,2M ene 30 18:53 System.map-3.11.0-15-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3,2M feb  3 23:20 System.map-3.11.0-17-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3,2M mar 11 20:06 System.map-3.11.0-19-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3,2M abr  1 23:08 System.map-3.11.0-20-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 5,4M oct 23  2013 vmlinuz-3.11.0-13-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 5,4M nov 12 18:33 vmlinuz-3.11.0-14-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 5,4M ene 30 18:53 vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 5,4M feb  3 23:20 vmlinuz-3.11.0-17-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 5,4M mar 11 20:06 vmlinuz-3.11.0-19-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 5,4M abr  1 23:08 vmlinuz-3.11.0-20-generic
```

Questions:

Among those files in boot folder, which can be removed?

Thank you:)

Comment: remove all the kernals execpt the current kernal(`uname -r`)

Comment: hmmm @AvinashRaj I consider it better practice to at least have 2   :)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to install [Ubuntu Tweaks](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/):

[image]

Select the kernels you want to remove and go on --- I normally leave the newest of the current series and (if available) the older of the previous (like a 3.8 kernel).

**Be careful** that if you have some manually installed kernel (upstream, testing, etc) the janitor will remove **all** your automatically upgraded kernels if you tell him to remove all kernel in the list --- and then you need to reinstall manually `linux-generic` to go back to the standard kernel line. Do not delete the most recent old kernel as a rule of thumb and be safe.

Normally you have the error while upgrading, and that means you can have a failed upgrade linging; I would advise a

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

after the cleanup.